# Unexpected computer shutdown while python file wasn't saved

Tags: python, recovery

I was adding final touches to a python code when my computer unexpectedly shut down. When I turned it back on and opened the file, it was blank. Is it possible for me to recover the contents of that file?

Comment: You didn't press `CTRL + S` even once while writing your whole program? And it depends on which IDE you have. WingIDE has an autosave.

Comment: This is an issue with whatever editor you were using, not Python.

Comment: I saved it constantly. My computer shut down while I was editing, though.

Comment: I was typing the code right into IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

You can look for a .swp or other backup file by typing in a terminal:

```
$ls -a /path/to/python/file
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless it was backed up somewhere automatically, it's gone permanently.